# How do I access math constants (eg. M_PI) in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: math, visual-c++, constants

I want to use the math constants, such as M_PI and M_E, in Visual C++ 2008. I assumed they were defined in the cmath header.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[They are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6(v=vs.90).aspx), but you also need to `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before you `#include <cmath>`

Comment: Note that other includes can implicitly do including `<cmath>`, so prefer to place `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before any header includes.

Place define into `stdafx.h` if you use precompiled headers.